# Simple circuit- Diode and the output voltage

Tags: diodes, output

I have found the current right but I thought **22V-2.2k(4.84mA)-0.7** would be equal to V0 (or **2.2k(4.84mA)**, voltage from lower branch- both are equal and so no inconsistency), why is my logic wrong and where did 1.2k come from?

[image]

Comment: That's a typo followed by calculation mistake. It should be \$2.2\,k\Omega\$ instead of \$1.2\,k\Omega\$

Comment: so the answer is wrong as well? it should also be **2.2k(4.84mA)=10.65V**? @nidhin

Comment: Yes. If the schematic is correct, then the answer should be 10.648 V

Comment: Or the value of lower branch resistor might be 1.2 kΩ

Answer (score 1, accepted):

nidhin was right, in your calculation you have for the second resistor 1.2kOhm instead of 2.2kOhm
I've calculated it for you here.

[image]